# Stack Overflow showing different messages in different browsers at same time

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, homepage

Today I observed one peculiar behaviour regarding the Stack Overflow home page message.

See the images for Internet Explorer and chrome.

**In IE**
[image: IE screenshot with login]

**In Chrome**
[image: Chrome screenshot with login]

Why this message difference? I have cleared y cache and checked but is it not surprising?

Comment: You were logged in on IE and not in Chrome?  Try it again but keep the top bar in your images.

Comment: I wasn't logged on ie or chrome

Comment: And I think this is bug

Comment: I'm sure you're not lying, but I need to search the pudding for the proof, if you don't mind.

Comment: Might be A/B testing...

Answer (score 12):

This is [an A/B test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing)  we are running, comparing two variations of the hero unit shown on Stack Overflow to anonymous users.

You're seeing two different pages because your browsers were placed in different groups (obviously, we do *not* track you across browsers!).

---

You should see different messages on the question page hero unit too, by the way.

Comment: Just curious: Why is this called *hero unit?*

Comment: We are all hero's @Wrzlprmft, because we keep coming back despite being pushed from A to B ... ;)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Wish I could tell you, but that name predates me here. I strongly suspect we used it because that's what bootstrap called it at that time. Why did bootstrap call it this way, though... [Who knows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871173/what-does-hero-unit-mean)!

Comment: @Wrzlprmft We're probably misusing it somewhat, but "hero" is a [web design term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_image).

Comment: Looks like the hero unit was renamed to Jumbotron in some recent Bootstrap update, see [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/). :) /cc @Wrzlprmft.